# What is a Plutus script witnessed tx input?

Tags: plutus

I'm getting the following error when trying to consume a UTXO at a script address.

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 1 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with:
transaction input 1 (in the order of the TxIds) is not a Plutus script witnessed tx input and cannot be spent using a Plutus script witness.
```

My first tx-in is the UTXO at the script address I'd like to consume, the second tx-in is just a UTXO with lovelace that I'm attempting to use to pay the script with.

~ Full Details ~

##### Transaction

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
--alonzo-era \
--mainnet \
--tx-in b4accf06d29a0d54a83e5d2b623d4cd361c6899408fd87cfa1437f42b83a8628#1 \
--tx-in d3e81062af7a78c02ae7bd3254092f83a647ee239ac65e52b13bd2cc7b9b00d4#0 \
--tx-in-script-file ../Vendere/market.plutus \
--tx-in-datum-file ../Vendere/datum-e986d38f4ead45a4f909cb51d61d8d95efc72b12d9302cdd040974d1-Hoskinsons2795.json \
--tx-in-redeemer-file ../Vendere/buy.json \
--required-signer ../Vendere/payment2.skey \
--tx-in-collateral b4accf06d29a0d54a83e5d2b623d4cd361c6899408fd87cfa1437f42b83a8628#0 \
--tx-out "addr1qxynjszluq9wekl4ap0d087cchn3pun5yn34z4nyturcclrpncrywfgdf5yw89f3pwqk86k2cn8d8y8czqaeg9ctsa0sw6z6dr + 1 e986d38f4ead45a4f909cb51d61d8d95efc72b12d9302cdd040974d1.Hoskinsons2795" \
--tx-out "addr1q84j8yjtf6lx0f8f4pkecjzj5qu2y38f2l820nuu850qv9z6vk9t3l3dnyxdvqdtqs40hm2d2v8mzk3zqxaf73s7xkase7n4y6 + 50000000" \
--change-address $(cat ../Vendere/payment.addr) \
--protocol-params-file ../Vendere/pparams.json \
--out-file ../Vendere/test-alonzo.tx
```

##### Datum

```
{
  "constructor": 0,
  "fields": [
    {
      "bytes": "01eb23924b4ebe67a4e9a86d9c4852a038a244e957cea7cf9c3d1e06145a658ab8fe2d990cd601ab042afbed4d530fb15a2201ba9f461e35bb"
    },
    { "int": 50000000 },
    { "bytes": "e986d38f4ead45a4f909cb51d61d8d95efc72b12d9302cdd040974d1" },
    { "bytes": "486f736b696e736f6e7332373935" }
  ]
}
```

##### Redeemer

```
{"constructor":1,"fields":[]}
```

##### Validator

https://github.com/OnChainLabs/Vendere/blob/main/src/Market/Onchain.hs#L60

Comment: Can you share the code that’s giving you this error?

Comment: @MitchellTurner Done! Should have all relevant details now

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, the order of my commands was wrong. The `--tx-in` for the script address needs to be just before the `--tx-in-script-file` :)